# How do authenticate a user with Custom Login credentials when using Backfire?

Tags: backbone.js, firebase, firebase-security

What is the best way to authenticate a user through the Custom Login flow described here (https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html) when using the Backbone wrapper?

Please take a look at the collection below.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'libs/firebase/firebase.min',
    'libs/firebase/backbone-firebase.min'
], function($, _, Backbone, Firebase, Backfire){

    return Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({

        initialize: function(){
            var self = this;
            self.firebase = "https://mybackboneapp.firebaseio.com/notifications/" + window.User.id;
        }
    });
});
```

When I use the method described below it works fine.

```
var dataRef = new Firebase("https://mybackboneapp.firebaseio.com/notifications/" + window.User.id);
// Log me in.
dataRef.auth(window.User.firebase_token, function(error) {
  if(error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Login Succeeded!");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have already generated a valid Firebase authentication token, I would recommend creating a new Firebase reference, authenticating it, and then passing it to BackFire.

Each of the Backbone pieces that descend from `Backbone.Firebase` accept *either* a string **or** a Firebase reference when created. If you pass a string, as you do in your example above, then a new Firebase reference will be created for you via `new Firebase(...)`, but passing in a reference of your own creation will allow you to directly invoke `.auth(<token>)` on it.

For example:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-namespace>.firebaseio.com");
ref.auth(<token>);
var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Todo,
  firebase: new Backbone.Firebase(ref)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom login is done using [one of the helper libraries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html#helper-libraries). Since this uses your secret to generate tokens, it's not something that would be done client-side (i.e. through the Backbone MVVM lib or Backfire).

You would set up a server process (e.g. node.js) and run your custom token generator there, then connect via HTTP or by ferrying requests for tokens through Firebase, in order to generate tokens.